# Recursive sql query to obtain change history

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Consider a  table

```
with test_tbl as (
select 5 as curuid, 7 as prevuid, 40 amount, 'increase by 20'  reason  from dual 
union 
select 7 as curuid,10 as prevuid,20 amount ,'decrease by 10'  reason  from dual
union 
select 10 as curuid,null as prevuid,30 amount, null  reason  from dual
union 
select 4 as curuid,null as prevuid,50 amount, null reason  from dual
)
select  *  from test_tbl
```

Each record has a `current uid` and an `amount`.

Now, each time there is an a change of the `amount` new record is created with new `uid` and its previous `uid` is set to the `uid` of the record being changed also the reason of change is set.

Thus, uid 5 comes from uid 7 increased by 20, which in turn comes from uid 10 increased by 10. uid=10 was an initial record.

I would like to create an sql that will take a uid as a parameter and will return all the history for the uid given.

From  the above  example, the query would return all the records except for the one with curuid=4 (which has nothing to do with the history of the record 5)

```
5   7   40  increase by 20
7   10  20  decrease by 10
10      30
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hierarchical query and `START WITH` the `uid` you want to get the history for:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl (curuid, prevuid, amount, reason ) as
  SELECT  5,    7, 40, 'increase by 20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  7,   10, 20, 'decrease by 10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, NULL, 30,             NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  4, NULL, 50,             NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
select * 
from   test_tbl
start with curuid = 5
connect by PRIOR prevuid = curuid;
```

**Output**:

```
CURUID | PREVUID | AMOUNT | REASON        
-----: | ------: | -----: | :-------------
     5 |       7 |     40 | increase by 20
     7 |      10 |     20 | decrease by 10
    10 |    null |     30 | null
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2988553ac780b1bd00f38f39095f3865)*